# Google Maps is plotting only for positive lat/long values, resetting NaN if negative lat/longs are passed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am totally new to maps.
I am facing a problem.
The latitude and longitude values that i pass are getting assigned to `NaN` by a dynamically generated file when these `lat/long =values` are negative. 
The `code a-= x; b-= y` is making negative lat/lon values to null and accepting (not converting) positive lat/long values. Strange.
This piece of code gets executed at

```
  point = new GLatLng(lat, long);
```

where

```
        myIcon.shadow = null;
        myIcon.printShadow = null;
        myIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(5, 15);
```

and i am making markers as

```
gmarkers.sort(function () { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(0, 50), 1);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(51, 100), 5);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(101, 150), 6);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(151, 200), 7);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(201, 300), 8);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(301, 400), 9);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(401, 600), 10);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(601, 800), 11);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(801, 1100), 12);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(1101, 1500), 13);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(1501, 2000), 14);
        mgr.addMarkers(gmarkers.slice(2001, 999999), 15);

        mgr.refresh();
```

somebody please help me...thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as C# instead of vb.net?

Comment: to my understanding, problem lies in code:

Comment: myIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(5, 15); as for the marker, myIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(5, 15); takes values of icon and point. I am coding for the country Brazil. Can someone please tell if GPoint values chanc=ge with respect to country?

Comment: Can you show us the code where values for `lat` and `long` are assigned?

Comment: All the code you posted appears to be C#, but you tagged your question with javascript and vb.net.  You never mentioned either of those languages in your question.  If it is VB related, I suggest you update your question to reflect that.  If not, I suggest you retag it appropriately so you will get better answers.

Comment: @SteveDog All the code in the question looks like JavaScript to me! [Math.random](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp), [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), [GLatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)

Comment: @MarkJ fair enough.  I should have looked more closely.  In any event, it shouldn't be tagged as vb.net.

Comment: @SteveDog Agreed - I just removed the vb.net tag. Although I also answered the question, and ironically I only saw the question because I follow the Vb.Net tag

Comment: hi Mestek, i am fetching the lat long values from the db. i have been looking into this and now i am suspecting that the error might be because of a file markermanager.js where in it is defining the bounds of view for the map...  if (ne.x - sw.x + 1 >= gw) {
        // Computed grid bounds are larger than the world; truncate.
        sw.x = 0;
        ne.x = gw - 1;
    } the values i am providing belong to se which is not being checked i suppose. can u provide some suggessions pls???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was that of data. As for Brazillian culture, the decimal in the latitude and longitude values were being set to comma (,) instead of a decimal or period (.)
this can be resolved by doing a (Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
to avoid replacement.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should write

```
a = -x;
```

rather than

```
a -= x;
```

Because `a -= x` is shorthand for `a = a - x`